# how to get total sum of two tables and group responses with eloquent Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to create a query using eloquent where I need to know the total points summed by id, username and session_id.
but the result I get is not correct.

**my code**

```
$query = DB::table('advisors')
    ->select('advisors.id','advisors.nombre_comercial','session_details.session_id',
        DB::raw('SUM(session_details.spent_points + template_sales.price_points) AS suma_total'))
    ->join('consultancy_requests','advisors.id','=','consultancy_requests.advisor_id')
    ->whereBetween('consultancy_requests.created_at',[$from,$to])
    ->join('receipts','consultancy_requests.id','=','receipts.session_id')
    ->where('receipts.status',NULL)
    ->whereBetween('receipts.created_at',[$from,$to])
    ->join('session_details','consultancy_requests.consultancy_id','=','session_details.session_id')
    ->whereBetween('session_details.created_at',[$from,$to])
    ->join('template_sales','session_details.session_id','=','template_sales.session_id')
    ->whereBetween('template_sales.created_at',[$from,$to])
    ->groupBy('advisors.id','advisors.nombre_comercial','session_details.session_id')
    ->get();
```

**code responses**

[image: response]

**session_details table**

[image: session_details]

**template_sales table**

[image: template_sales]

this is the correct answer i want to get.

[image: respuesta_correcta]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of mistakes in your query that I noticed. For instance you don't need to **SUM** `(session_details.spent_points + template_sales.price_points)` because this is already performing the addition.

Instead of pointing out all these, let's break your problem down into smaller pieces; when query seems complicated it would be a good idea to break it down for better understanding. There seems to be a couple of tables but I will base my answer on the two tables provided, and that should give you a starting point.

Essentially, what you want is,

Get the sum of `spent_points` per `session_id`; so you need to `group by session_id` and `sum(spent_points)`

```
$sumSpentPointsQuery = DB::table('session_details')
                       ->select('session_id', DB::raw('SUM(spent_points) as sum_spent_points'))
                       ->groupBy('session_id');
```

Get the sum of `price_points` per `session_id`; so you need to `group by session_id` and `sum(price_points)`

```
$sumPricePointsQuery = DB::table('template_sales')
                       ->select('session_id', DB::raw('SUM(price_points) as sum_price_points'))
                       ->groupBy('session_id');
```

Now we need to get the addition of `sum_spent_points` and `sum_price_points`. This time our tables would be the results we got from the sub queries. So we can work with Laravel's `fromSub` and `joinSub` to get the result we want.

```
DB::query()
    ->select('ssp.session_id as session_id', DB::raw('sum_spent_points + sum_price_points as suma_total') )
    ->fromSub($sumSpentPointsQuery, 'ssp')
    ->joinSub($sumPricePointsQuery, 'spp', function($join){
         $join->on('ssp.session_id', '=', 'spp.session_id');
    })->get();
```

This query should produce the sql that represents this:

```
select ssp.session_id as session_id, (sum_spent_points + sum_price_points) as suma_total 
from 
  (select session_id, sum(spent_points) as sum_spent_points 
  from session_details group by session_id) ssp
inner join 
  (select session_id, sum(price_points) as sum_price_points 
  from template_sales group by session_id) spp 
on ssp.session_id = spp.session_id ;
```

Hope this kicks you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks to your help, you gave me a new perspective on how to see the problem and solve it.